# step in proof for gagliardo-nirenberg interpolation

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I am having difficulty with the proof of proposition 12.84 of [A First Course
in Sobolev Spaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470429217), 2nd Edition, by Giovanni Leoni. In particular, the
following intermediate result is proven:
$$|u(x)| \le (\alpha_N R^N)^{-1/q}\|u\|_{L^q} + R^\alpha|u|_{C^{o,\alpha}}\tag{1}$$
where $u$ is [Holder Continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition)
with constants $|u|_{C^{0,\alpha}}$ and $\alpha > 0$,
$R>0$, $\|\cdot\|_{L^q}$ is the [$L^q$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces) norm, $\alpha_N$ is a constant, and $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$.

From here, the proof then minimizes the right hand side with respect to $R$. In other words, they minimize
the following function:
$$g(t) = \alpha_N^{-1/q}t^{-N/q}\|u\|_{L^q} + t^\alpha|u|_{C^{o,\alpha}}\tag{2}$$
and get the following by inserting the minimum of (2) into 
(1).
$$\|u\|_{L^\infty} \le c\|u\|^{\theta_1}_{L^q}|u|^{1-\theta_1}_{C^{0,\alpha}} \tag{3}$$
where $\theta_1 = \alpha/(\alpha + N/q)$ and $c$ is a grouping of constant terms dependent on $\alpha, N,$ and $q$.
Since (1) is taken over all $x\in\mathbb{R}^R$, I see where the $\|u\|_{L^\infty}$
term comes from. However, I am having difficulty seeing how the right hand side is derived.

In particular, when I take the derivative of (2) and set it equal to 0, I get the following:
$$0 = g'(t) = -\frac{N}{q} \alpha_N^{-1/q} t^{-N/q - 1}\|u\|_{L^q} + \alpha t^{\alpha - 1}|u|_{C^{0,\alpha}} \tag{6}$$
which after a couple of algebra steps yields

$$t = \left(\frac{\alpha q |u|_{C^{0,\alpha}}}{\alpha_N^{-1/q}N\|u\|_{L^q}}\right)^{\alpha+N/q} = a\left(\frac{|u|_{C^{0,\alpha}}}{ \|u\|_{L^q}}\right)^{\alpha + N/q}\tag{4}.$$

Plugging $t$ in (4) into $R$ in (1) yields
$$(\alpha_N t^N)^{-1/q}\|u\|_{L^q} + t^\alpha|u|_{C^{o,\alpha}}
=
\alpha_N^{-1/q}a|u|^{\alpha+N/q}\|u\|^{1-\alpha-N/q} + a|u|^{\alpha+N/q+1}\|u\|^{-\alpha-N/q}.
\tag{5}
$$
From (5), I am not sure how to get to get to (3).

**Edit**:

To go from (6) to (4), the following steps are taken:
$$\frac{N}{q}\alpha_N^{-1/q}\|u\|_{L^q}t^{-N/q-1} = \alpha t^{\alpha - 1}|u|_{C^{0,\alpha}}$$
$$\frac{N}{q}\alpha_N^{-1/q}\|u\|_{L^q}t^{-N/q-\alpha} = \alpha |u|_{C^{0,\alpha}}$$
$$t^{-N/q-\alpha} = \frac{\alpha q |u|_{C^{0,\alpha}}}{\alpha_N^{-1/q}N \|u\|_{L^q}}$$
$$t = \left(\frac{\alpha q |u|_{C^{0,\alpha}}}{\alpha_N^{-1/q}N \|u\|_{L^q}}\right)^{\alpha + N/q}$$

Comment: I think your exponent in (4) is wrong. If you get the correct exponent, the exponents in (5) should be the same and yield (3).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited the answer to include my derivation. From what I can tell it looks correct. Is there something you see that is wrong with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last step contains an error. It should read
$$
t = (\ldots)^{-1/(\alpha + N/q)}.$$